# In Google Sheets, is it possible to display the contents of the active cell to another cell?

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Sheets, range N16:N29 has content referenced as a query from another sheet. If I select any one of those cells N16:N29, I'd like to have its content displayed at cell N10. When the active cell is no longer one of N16:N29, N10 is blank.

I haven't seen any mention of this and am curious if it's possible.

Comment: Yes.  See Script Below.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart < 10 && e.range.rowStart < 17) {
    sh.getRange("M1").setValue(e.range.getValue());
  }
}
```

I imported data into Sheet1 A2:J16 and used the onSelectionChange() triggers to display data in M1 when you select a cell inside of the imported range.

You just have to edit the if statement to set `e.range.columnStart > 15 && e.range.columnStart < 30 & e.range.rowStart == 14` and correct the sheet name and change M1 to N10

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'New Sheet Name' && e.range.columnStart > 15 && e.range.columnStart < 30 & e.range.rowStart == 14) {
    sh.getRange("N10").setValue(e.range.getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting **e: undefined** and **sh: undefined**

Comment: You cannot run this function directly unless you supply the event object that it normally gets from the trigger that is fired when a user makes a selection change.

Comment: Edit the sheet name and go make selection changes on that sheet in the appropriate ranges.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Form' && e.range.columnStart < 15 && e.range.columnStart > 13 && e.range.rowStart > 15 && e.range.rowStart < 30) {
    sh.getRange("N10").setValue(e.range.getValue());
  }
}
```

Cooper, thanks for your help! I'm new to Apps Script. I've been having trouble getting your code to work on my sheet. None of the selections I made would show at the target cell. After some experimenting, I changed **columnStart** from *>15 <30* to **<15 >13** and **rowStart** from *==14* to **>15 <30**. That worked.

The only thing I can't figure out is when I select a cell outside the script range (N16:N29), the target cell (N10) still holds the previous selection. I'd like for the target cell to go blank when that happens. Is that possible?