# display the contents of the active cell to another cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

someone asked these questions but it's not working, if possible, make corrections on the test file, please
Any of between N16:N29, 16 to 29 any one cell we select that cell text or value shows on yellow N10

[In Google Sheets, is it possible to display the contents of the active cell to another cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69843454/in-google-sheets-is-it-possible-to-display-the-contents-of-the-active-cell-to-a)

[TEST File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tKLdZvbWOp4W-saPQHuoOel5tyI_PdxiInhGddtR6hk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your request of `Any of between N16:N29, 16 to 29 any one cell we select that cell text or value shows on yellow N10`, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

**Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your provided Google Spreadsheet, and save the script. And, just in case, please reopen Google Spreadsheet.**

```js
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const sheetName = "Form"; // This is from your provided Spreadsheet.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const check = sheet.getSheetName() == sheetName && range.rowStart >= 16 && range.rowEnd <= 29 && range.columnStart == 14;
  const value = check ? range.getValue() : null;
  sheet.getRange("N10").setValue(value);
}
```

- When you want to use this script, please select one of the cells "N16:N29" of "Form" sheet. By this, the value of the selected cell is put into cell "N10".

#### Testing:

When this script is used using your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided Spreadsheet. So, please test this script using your provided Spreadsheet.
- The function `onSelectionChange` is automatically run by the simple trigger when a cell is selected. I used `onSelectionChange` of the simple trigger from `Any of between N16:N29, 16 to 29 any one cell we select that cell text or value shows on yellow N10`. So, when you directly run the function `onSelectionChange` with the script editor, an error like `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined.` occurs, because the event object `e` is not given. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee)

### Added:

About your following reply,

> it's working but if I have to remove this const value = check? range.getValue() : null; Means Whenever its out of range it will keep the old value is it possible?

In this case, how about the following sample script?

```js
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const sheetName = "Form"; // This is from your provided Spreadsheet.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const check = sheet.getSheetName() == sheetName && range.rowStart >= 16 && range.rowEnd <= 29 && range.columnStart == 14;
  if (!check) return;
  sheet.getRange("N10").setValue(range.getValue());
}
```

Comment: it's working but if I have to remove this *const value = check? range.getValue() : null;*  Means Whenever its out of range it will keep the old value is it possible?

Comment: @Sanjay Devani Thank you for replying. About your new question of `if I have to remove this const value = check? range.getValue() : null; Means Whenever its out of range it will keep the old value is it possible?`, I added one more sample script for this. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Comment: Works Great Thank you so much Replace  *const value = check ? range.getValue() : value;*

Comment: @Sanjay Devani Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Upon checking on the link you have shared, [In Google Sheets, is it possible to display the contents of the active cell to another cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69843454/in-google-sheets-is-it-possible-to-display-the-contents-of-the-active-cell-to-a), It is working on my end.

Just to note, the behavior of `onSelectionChange` function is, after allowing the authorization, you cannot run the function directly, you need to supply the object by *making a selection change on the sheet*, that is how the trigger is fired.

**this is an alternative solution:**

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var activeCell = e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell();
  var activeCellValue = activeCell.getValue();
  //Logger.log(activeCellValue)
  
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form"); // name of your sheet
  var targetCell = targetSheet.getRange("N10"); 
  
  if(e.range.rowStart >=16 && e.range.rowStart <= 29 && e.range.columnStart==14){
    targetCell.setValue(activeCellValue);
  }
}
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain thoroughly how is it not working on your end?

Comment: it's working but if I have to remove this *const value = check? range.getValue() : null;*  Means Whenever its out of range it will keep the old value is it possible?